# best practice for writing R codes

Tags: r

Hi I just had a quick question regarding writing faster  R scripts using multiple functions:
which of the following will run faster assuming exactly the same content in each example?
functions within functions i.e

```
function(args)
{
function_using_previous_function_output(args)
{ manipulation of arguments}

}
```

functions that pass stuff outside of each other:

```
function(args)
{return(output}
}

function_using_previous_function_output(output)
{
manipulation of arguments
}
```

Is there a best practice for style or optimisation out of these ??

Many thanks!

Comment: I don't think you'll see much speed difference either way, but why don't you test it with `microbenchmark` or similar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Short answer;** you're looking down the wrong avenue in terms of optimising code.

**Long answer;**

The contents are almost always the most important aspect of a script's performance. You should only really be fudging your syntax if your code is already parallelised, vectorised, Rcpp-ised and byte-compiled (require(compiler);enableJIT(3)), and you *still* need more speed.

In the unlikely case where you need to change the shape of the code itself to gain speed, these articles are your friend

http://www.r-bloggers.com/speeding-up-r-computations/
http://radfordneal.wordpress.com/2010/08/15/two-surpising-things-about-r/

To answer your original question; you should determine the efficiency using the system.time() function; I doubt there will be a statistically significant difference either way

Comment: Why enableJIT(3) returns 0 in first time you type it, and it returns 3 in second time?

Answer (score 3):

I've been writing a package for simulation which uses many functions to perform different steps based on different processes of a biological model. Then those functions themselves are called by the main function which does the simulation by calling them and occasionally doing some stuff itself with the output of those sub-functions. The point is it relies heavily on functions in functions; I don't see much of a speed difference when I've had a series of steps in my main simulation function - then to tidy it up I put those steps into a sub-function. However I prefer it because when each sub function finishes, any variable or rubbish used during the sub-function but is not actually used for any result or `return()`'d is eliminated when the sub-function ends, meaning less chance of accidentally modifying variables when you don't want to. Usually the main speed differences in R I've seen come when you have a loop operation and you vectorize it or use Rcpp to do it in C++. Most core stuff in R is fast now anyway and is already byte compiled.

Comment: +1 for using many functions. Using hierarchies of functions (e.g. one function to read a file, a second to read a directory of files which uses the previous function) makes easier to understand code, and makes it easier to reuse code, I.e. create new functionality from these small building blocks.